# Inserting > at the start of each line in reply e-mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, reply

In my Rails app I have a mail section in which I want to append a `>` character at the start of each line when replying to a message. The challenge is, how do I know when to insert a `>` character given the block of text doesn't contain carriage returns according to the width of the textbox.

Comment: < rather than >? That's a bit unconventional isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Rails answer, but I would suggest cutting off all lines > 75 characters.

This is how most (proper) email clients behave. Also don't forget to set the In-Reply-To: and References: headers.